# How do I see common Items between 2 array of Objects

Tags: linq-to-sql, intersection

How do I see common Items between 2 array of Objects. My intersect is not returning anything. The object is created from a Linq to SQL class.

Comment: Could you please post some code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to override the object's Equals method. You can find [some guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) at Microsoft's web site.

I've provided a sample below:

```
public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
{
    if (obj != null && obj is MyClass)
    {
        MyClass obj2 = (MyClass)obj;
        return (obj2.ID == this.ID);
    }
}
```

If you do not override this method, any kind of sort/intersect/comparison will compare the objects based on their reference; so, if two objects refer to the same spot in memory, they are considered "equal."

Comment: My class definition is in the web service and I am trying to do the intersect in the client side. I overrided the Equals method still didnt work.

Comment: Your comments don't really give me enough detail to provide you with a better solution. If you could provide an example of what you're doing, it would make for a more succinct question.

Answer (score 1):

In Java atleat, unless you override the .equals() operator, it will test for object equality (essentially using ==).  That might be why the intersection is emtpy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you override the Equals method?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to sort them, of course.